# Preseed - Install OS on smallest disk

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, preseed

I'm trying to create a preseed file for my systems with 2 HDD's. I want to install the OS on the smallest disk, but on some systems, this disk is labeled as sdb and others sda. Is there a way to select the smallest disk?

```
d-i partman/early_command string \
  PRIMARYDISK=/dev/$(lsblk -Sn -o NAME --sort SIZE --include 8 | head -n 1) ; \
  debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$PRIMARYDISK" ;
```

I've seen people doing the above command, but I just get lsblk not found.
Any ideas?

Comment: Something to try: add the directory in front of `lsblk`?

Comment: Try `which -a lsblk` to see if the binary exists and is in the path.

Comment: Open Gnome Disks, it will show you visually which disk is which and how big, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This worked using the 20.04 Ubuntu Server legacy installer

```
d-i partman/early_command string \
  PRIMARYDISK=/dev/$( X=$(cat /sys/block/sd?/size|sort -n|head -1); for i in /sys/block/sd?; do [ $X -eq $(cat $i/size) ] && echo $i | sed -e s#.*/## ; done ) ; \
  debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$PRIMARYDISK"
```

It uses the `/sys` filesystem to find the smallest disk.  `lsblk` is not available in the installer environment.

I'm pretty sure you are using a command [from an answer of mine](https://serverfault.com/questions/1050396/debian-preseed-select-smallest-drive-for-os) that was based on the assumption that `lsblk` is available.  That is because the comments referred to [a blog post](https://www.cms.waikato.ac.nz/%7Edbaird/work/determining-disk-device-in-ubuntu-preseed.html) where `lsblk` was used in a similar way.  It may be that `lsblk` used to be available in older releases, is available in Debian, or the blog is wrong.